# Displaying a float as a QString on a QLabel displays a "G" where a dot "." should go

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtgui, qlabel

I'm trying to display a float in a QLabel but for some reason it keeps displaying a "G" right where the dot should go. In other words if the result is 1.23445 it displays 1G23445.

Please look at the following code...

```
float myFloat = 2.09863591;
QString floatAsString = QString::number(myFloat, 'f',8);
qDebug()<< "Number as String: "<< floatAsString;// here it displays 2.09863591
ui->label->setText(floatAsString);// here it displays 2G09863591
```

Why is that when I display the float result on a QLabel it outputs a "G" instead of a "."?

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried different formats ('g', 'G', etc?)?

Comment: Yes, I tried QString::number(myFloat, 'g',8) and I get the same result; I also tried QString::number(myFloat, 'e',8) and I get 2G09863591e+0. I tried g, G, e and E.

Comment: 'f' works for me. You are probably doing something wrong. Pasting more code would help, I guess, to pin the issue further down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. You are probably doing something wrong, like not rebuilt properly, etc.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QApplication>

#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    float f = 2.09863591;
    QString s = QString::number(f, 'f', 8);
    qDebug()<< "Test:" << s;
    QLabel label;
    label.setText(s);
    label.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4):QT += widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Output

```
Number as String: "2.0986359"
```

Comment: You are right, this code should work, I just tried displaying the result in a new label and it worked, it may be something wrong with the label I'm using. I will update this thread if I find what was wrong with the label. Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know why but I just deleted the label and put a new one and it worked ok, no idea what was wrong with that label.

Comment: FYI - 
I have been playing around with this trying to find what was wrong with the label and I found out that the font I was using with this label was causing the issue. The font I was using was "Geeza Pro" and as soon as I changed it to Arial it starting displaying the "." correctly.